# problem with select statement mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

This has annoyed me for a while now. I am trying this `query` in phpmyadmin.

```
select `id` from `users` where `fb_id` = 507292797 limit 1
```

This returns the value `13`, so why doesn't this work:

```
                $sql =  "select `id` from `users` " .
                        "where `fb_id` = :fb_id " .
                        "limit 1";
                try 
                {
                    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql); 
                    $stmt->bindParam(':fb_id', $fb_id2, PDO::PARAM_INT);

                    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
                    $result = $stmt->execute();

                    $stmt->closeCursor(); 
                }       
                catch (Exception $e)
                {
                die ($e->getMessage() ); 
                }

                echo "id: " . $fb_id2 . " var_dump: " . var_dump($user); 
                exit();
```

This returns:

id: `507292797` var_dump: `bool(false)`

When var_dump should return `$user['id'] = 13`

Can somebody see what I am doing wrong here?

ps. here is my db connection function if that matter

```
        $dsn = "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME;
        $driver_options = array( PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8' );

        try
        {
            $this->db = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $driver_options);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing things in this order :

- Preparing the statement
- Binding the variables
- Trying to fetch data from the statement
- Executing the statement

The two last steps should be in the inverse order : **you must execute the statement before you can fetch data** *(that's obtained by executing it)*.

Basically, instead of using this :

```
// fetch, then execute ???
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

You should use that :

```
// Execute, **then** fetch
$stmt->execute();
$user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are fetching before executing?